# Downoald multiple files on same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, download

I have Listbox full with links like this: http://example.com/sorted/Avicii/Avicii+-+Wake+Me+Up.mp3 and I wanna download them all on same time any suggestions?
this code I use to download a single file

```
 private void txtUrl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //  function that enter the file name automatically in the savefiledialog.
            Uri uri = new Uri(txtUrl.Text);
            // Save the file name to the string.
            filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
        }
        catch
        {
            // no need  need an exception message.
        }
    }
    private void DownloadFile(string url, string save)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            // Run code every time the download changes.
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(Changed);
            // Run codes when file download has been completed.
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                           client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), save);
```

Comment: First suggestion: post the code you have tried so far. Second suggestion: explain where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I have way how to download just one file but isnt practical @DigiFriend

Comment: Loops are you friend. As are asynchronous methods.

Comment: they are no other ways @DigiFriend ??

Comment: Such as? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried looping through `listBox.Items`?

Comment: @GabrielJ - how is that relevant?

Comment: I need confirmation every time to save file and directory to put looping the items well not help at less if have a way to automate the confirmation @DigiFriend

Comment: Why do you need confirmation? We have seen zero code, so we have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: @DigiFriend i edit question u can see the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution could look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace SillyCSharpNameSpace
{
    public class VerboseDownloaderClassName
    {
        private string downloadFile(string url, string localDir)
        {
            try
            {
                var localPath = Path.Combine(localDir, Path.GetFileName(url));
                using (var wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.DownloadFile(url, localPath);
                    return localPath;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void DownloadAll(List<string> urls)
        {
            urls.AsParallel()
                .Where(url => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(20)
                .Select(url => downloadFile(url, "."));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure if you work with WinForms or ASP.NET you can figure out how to take an url string from a list box item. And note, that Path.GetFileName() works only for the form you have provided - with the file name at the end of URL, without any URL parameters. `AsParallel` method parallelizes the downloading work into 20 "threads". I think it should be enough for your purpose.

Bonus. This is the same in F#, just because I can ;o)

```
open System.IO
open System.Net
open FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq // from NuGet FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq

let downloadFile dir url =
    let localPath = Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName url)
    try
        use wc = new WebClient()
        wc.DownloadFile(url, localPath)
        Some localPath
    with ex ->
        printfn "Can't download file from %s: %A" url ex
        None

let downloadAll (urls: string list) =
    urls
    |> PSeq.withDegreeOfParallelism 20 // 20 threads
    |> PSeq.choose (downloadFile ".")
```

Comment: Ur welcome. Here at stackoverflow they appreciate help accepting the answer ;o)

Comment: sure thing just i was away